# Use Macro to Split Data into 2 Columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

Use Macro to Split Data into 2 Columns.

Using Excel 2013 on a Windows 10 laptop.  Have used Macros in Word, but new to using them in Excel.

The goal is to take everything beyond the first word in a cell that may contain several words (and not necessarily the same number of words), and “move” it to the same row, next column.  For example, here’s a simple table:

```
Cell B2:  Tom This is a test.
Cell B3:  Dick This is another test.
Cell B4:  Harry This is a third test.
```

When placing the cursor into B2 (for example) and running the macro, it should leave “Tom “ in B2, cut and paste “This is a test.” into C2, and move down one row and left one column to Cell B3 to prepare to do the same on “Dick This is another test.” although at this point, if I didn’t want to execute the macro on B3, I could for example manually move the cursor down to B4, and run the macro there, to leave “Harry “ in B4 and move “This is a third test.” to C4.

So here’s what I’ve tried (with results/problem described below):

Position the cursor in the starting cell, let’s say B2, which contains “Tom This is a test.”
Click on Developer tab.
Make sure Use Relative References is activated.
Record Macro.
Give it a name, Assign a shortcut key, and enter a Description, as desired.  Store Macros in this workbook.
F2 to edit.  Goes into Edit mode, with cursor at right end of entry.  (Remember, pre-I’ve positioned the cursor in B2.)
Press Home to move to start (left) of cell.
Ctrl+RightArrow to move past First Name and spacebar, to the “T” in “T”his is a test.
Hold down Shift key and Press End to select “This is a test.”
Press Ctrl+X to cut.
Press Tab to move to Cell C2.
Press Ctrl+V to paste “This is a test.” into Cell C2.
Press Enter to move down one row and left one column to Cell B3, to prepare to do the same (if desired) on “Dick This is another test.”
Stop Recording.

The problem is after recording the macro (as above), when I go to subsequently execute the macro, regardless of which cell I start in (whether for example B3 or even a completely blank cell somewhere else in the sheet), instead of leaving the person’s name in Column B, and putting the rest of their info in Column C, it puts “Tom “ in Column B, and “This is a test.” in Column C.

I realize that each time it’s going back to B2 and working on the “Tom” information… but why?  (I thought that’s what Use Relative References was supposed to take care of.)

I also realize I could go to Data, Text to Columns, and separate out the remaining words after the name into separate columns that way… but when saying the columns are to be delimited by spacebars, it takes every word and puts it into a separate column.  I don’t want to do this.  I want the person’s name to remain in the starting column, and everything after the person’s name to just be put into the next column to the right.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?  I’d rather do it from the macro record process, rather than using VBA… but will use VBA if there’s no other way to do it… although I’d need an explanation of what the applicable VBA steps would be.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thank you for specifying what you've tried in detail.

Generally speaking you would need to replace this:

```
Range("B2")
```

With the word "Selection" then make appropriate adjustments that refer to that instead of B2. You can use .Offset(row,col) to specify relative positions to a Range object. Selection is a Range object, so you can use that to say "to the right of" or "the next row".

If you include your code in your post in a code block, we can take a look at it, but this should work:

```
Public Sub SplitOnFirstSpace()

Dim both_parts As String
Dim first_part As String
Dim the_rest As String

'This macro should only work on one cell

If Selection.Rows.Count > 1 Or Selection.Columns.Count > 1 Then 'more than one row or column selected

    'display a message then exit the subroutine
    MsgBox "More than one row or column selected." & vbCrLf & _
            Selection.AddressLocal, vbCritical, "Split on first space"

    Exit Sub

End If

' get the value in the selected cell
both_parts = Selection

If InStr(1, both_parts, " ") = 0 Then 'there were no spaces in the selected cell

    ' do nothing

Else

    'Get the text to the left of the first space:

    'LEFT(string,length) gets the first 'length' characters from 'string'
    'InStr(start,String1,String2) gets the first position of 'String2' within 'String1'
    ' (after starting the search at position 'start')
    first_part = Left(both_parts, InStr(1, both_parts, " "))

    'Get everything after the first space:

    'Mid(string,start,length) gets a substring of length 'length'
    ' from string 'string', starting at position 'start'
    'Len() gets the length of a string
    the_rest = Mid(both_parts, Len(first_part) + 1, Len(both_parts))

    'put the first part in the selected cell
    Selection = first_part

    'put the rest in the cell to the right of the selected cell

    'Range.Offset(rowoffset,columnoffset) lets you refer to ranges relative to a specific range
    ' in this case, the offset is relative to the selected cell
    Selection.Offset(0, 1) = the_rest

End If

' move down to the next row
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select

End Sub
```

I edited the function to specify that you should only use this macro when one cell is selected and to do nothing in case a cell is selected that has no spaces in it.

For reference, the functions used:

[InStr](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function) function to search for the position of a string within another string.

[Left](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/left-function) function to return a limited number of characters from the beginning of a string.

[Mid](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/mid-function) function to return a substring from an arbitrary position within a string.

[Offset](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset) property of Range object, to refer to ranges relative to a given range.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of doing this, using Excel VBA methods, also demonstrating that what gets recorded by the macro recorder is often not the best method of accomplishing something.

[image]

```
Option Explicit
Sub SplitOnFirstSpace()
    'declare variables
    Dim rg As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range

'set range and worksheet variables
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2") 'or whatever
With ws
    Set rg = .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
End With

'Split on first space only
For Each c In rg.Rows

    'check if any spaces so as not to repeat the split if already done
    If InStr(c, " ") > 0 Then _
        c.Resize(columnsize:=2) = Split(c, " ", 2)
Next c

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers... but still having difficulty getting this to work.

I pasted the codes you both sent into the VBA editor (one at a time, of course), closed the VBA editor, and tried running it, but neither would work for me.  (Got the "Windows 10 Default Beep" each time.)  Now I'm new to using VBA, so if there's something else I need to do in relation to this, pls advise.

Meanwhile, here's the VBA code generated by my recording the macro.  Again, the thought process behind it is... F2 to edit the cell, Home to get to the first character, Ctrl+RightArrow to skip over the name, hold down Shift and press End to select the rest of the entry, Ctrl+X to cut, Tab to move to the next column, Ctrl+V to paste [that is, everything except the person's name], Enter to move down one row and left one column:

Sub Macro8()
'
' Macro8 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+M
'
    ActiveCell.Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Tom "
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Range("A1").Select
End Sub

Like I indicated, when I record the macro, starting in B2, which is where I initially have "Tom This is a test." it (as desired) "leaves" "Tom " in B2, and puts "This is a test." into C2.

But when I then execute the macro (using the keyboard shortcut I have assigned, Ctrl+Shift+M) from ANY cell... such as B3 which initially has "Dick This is another test." it puts "Tom " (instead of "Dick ") in B3 and "This is a test." (instead of "This is another test.") into C3... that is, the exact info that was originally in B2 (but splitting it after "Tom ")... rather than doing what I expected, that is, taking what's initially in B3 ("Dick This is another test.") and "leaving" "Dick " in B3 and putting "This is another test." into C3.

Similarly, if I execute it from even a blank cell anywhere on the sheet (say, for example, C14), it puts "Tom " into C14 and "This is a test." into D14.

I can see in MY code that "Tom " is part of it (as desired... at least for the first execution)... but nowhere do I see "This is a test." even though it's indeed putting that into the next cell to the right.  Why wouldn't this show up in the code?

So now it seems I actually have 2 questions:  (1) my original one, about what's wrong with my code and what do I need to do to fix it; and (2) what could I be doing wrong about pasting your recommended codes into the VBA editor, and they don't work for me (I just get the "Windows 10 Default Beep" when trying to run them)?

As a matter of interest, I converted this Excel sheet into a Word table, and was able to create a macro in Word to do this very task... but that's the long way around the barn, and doesn't help me develop proficiency in Excel!

Again, thanks so much for any ideas and help.